# $\{v_n \} $ is bounded in $W_0^{1,q}$ for $ 1 \leq q < \frac{N}{N-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have a encountered to a problem in reading article .

Can someone look at the page **9** [in this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uam.es%2Fpersonal_pdi%2Fciencias%2Fmapperez%2Fultimos_trabajos%2FPerezPrimoRevised.pdf&ei=78m7VPjuFsP5UtKegnA&usg=AFQjCNEWUiwjrczoQQhswakkxluVyOuXHQ&sig2=8W3V033ABeiUkr3cxtf2Qw&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d24) and give a hint that 
why $\{v_n \} $ is bounded in $W_0^{1,q}$ for $ 1 \leq q < \frac{N}{N-1}$ and also I am curious to know that $\frac{N}{N-1}$ comes from where ?

and also why $\{T_k(v_n) \} $ is bounded in $W_0^{1,2}$

I am so Thanked for helping .

Comment: Seems like the exponent is the Sobolev exponent for $p=1$.

Comment: Right, isn't this just the Sobolev Embedding Theorem?  $v_n$ is 2 anti-derivatives of $f_n$, and hence $\nabla v_n$ is one anti-derivative of $f_n$, and the operation of one anti-derivative takes $L^1$ to $L^q$ for $q$ in the specified range.  For your last question, it tells you to look in reference [6].

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Would you please elaborate a bit more on how you are deducing that the weak gradient $\nabla v_{n}$ exists and how  you arrive at uniform boundedness of the $\left\{v_{n}\right\}$ in $W_{0}^{1,q}$? It would seem like uniform boundedness would be arrived at by controlling $\left\|v_{n}\right\|_{W_{0}^{1,q}}$ with $\left\|f_{n}\right\|_{L^{1}}\leq\left\|f\right\|_{L^{1}}$.

Comment: $v_n = -\Delta u_n$, so $ - \Delta v_n = - \nabla \cdot \nabla v_n =  f_n \in L^1$. Therefore, $\nabla v_n \in W^{1,1} \subset L^q$.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig $v_n(x) = \int_\Omega k(x,y) f_n(y) \, dy$ where $k$ is the appropriate Green's function.  So $\nabla_x v_n(x) = \int_\Omega \nabla_x k(x,y) f_n(y) \, dy$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Thank you for your response. I am still a bit confused. In this [paper's introduction](http://www.math.unipr.it/~lunardi/Files/MetaLuna.pdf), the authors state that the "domain of realization of the Laplacian in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is not contained in $W^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$" if $n>1$. However, it continuously embeds in $W^{1+\beta,1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for any $\beta\in (0,1)$--they don't prove this, though. I guess I'm not following how you get that all the second order weak partial derivatives belong to $L^{1}$ in this case.

Comment: Generally Sobolev embeddings don't work well when $p$ or $q$ is 1.  $W^{2,p}$ is where all derivatives up to order 2 exist and are in $L^p$, whereas the domain of realization of the Laplacian merely requires that the Laplacian exists in $L^p$.  To get from, say, $\Delta u$ to $\partial^2 f/\partial x_1^2$ or other 2nd order partial derivatives typically requires a singular integral, namely $\int_\Omega \partial_{x_1}^2 k(x,y) u(y) \, dy$.  And typically these singular integrals are bounded from $L^p$ to $L^p$ when $1<p<\infty$, but not when $p = 1$ or $p = \infty$.

Comment: If the domain is $\mathbb R^2$, then these singular integrals are compositions of the so called Riesz transforms.  There I know the theory rather well.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Sorry, my brain may be a bit fried today, but how then are you obtaining then that $\nabla v_{n}\in W^{1,1}$? I appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: That was my mistake.  I should have said $W^{1+\beta,1}$.  That was my brain failing to work, not yours.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Professor Montgomery-Smith, if you have time and/or the inclination, I would appreciate any thoughts of yours related to [proving](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395989/domain-of-realization-of-laplacian-in-l1-mathbbrn) the continuous embedding into $W^{1+\beta,1}$, for $\beta\in(0,1)$.